# Problema al agregar widget (doctoralia)

Tags: javascript, html, css, basic

recién empiezo a aprender sobre el desarrollo de paginas web y estoy haciendo una pagina sencilla para un médico, quien me ha pedido agregar un widget a su pagina. 
El código del widget es proporcionado por la página Doctoralia, y las instrucciones del sitio con copiar el código que se genera tal cual y pegarlo en el código fuente de tu página.

El código generado es así:

a id="zl-url" class="zl-url" href="https://www.doctoralia.es/rafael-ecija-sanchez/psicologo/malaga" rel="nofollow" data-zlw-doctor="rafael-ecija-sanchez" data-zlw-type="big" data-zlw-opinion="true" data-zlw-hide-branding="true">Rafael Écija Sánchez - Doctoralia.es!function($_x,_s,id){var js,fjs=$_x.getElementsByTagName(_s)[0];if(!$_x.getElementById(id)){js = $_x.createElement(_s);js.id = id;js.src = "//platform.docplanner.com/js/widget.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","zl-widget-s");

Pero yo copio y pego eso y no está jalando el js, he tratado poniendolo en el archivo de js del sitio, en la etiqueta head, al final de body, y tal cual como está directo en el body. Lo único que se puede ver es el link que te lleva al sitio de doctoralia.
No sé que puede ser, si es un fallo mio o de doctoralia, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

he revisado el código y he notado que no tienes las etiquetas `<a></a>`, y tampoco `<script></script>`
La etiqueta `<a>` es para enlaces, y la etiqueta `<script>` para código Javascript.
Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```html
<a id="zl-url" class="zl-url" href="https://www.doctoralia.es/rafael-ecija-sanchez/psicologo/malaga" rel="nofollow"
data-zlw-doctor="rafael-ecija-sanchez" data-zlw-type="big" data-zlw-opinion="true" data-zlw-hide-branding="true">Rafael
Écija Sánchez - Doctoralia.es</a><script>!function($_x,_s,id){var
js,fjs=$_x.getElementsByTagName(_s)[0];if(!$_x.getElementById(id)){js = $_x.createElement(_s);js.id = id;js.src =
"//platform.docplanner.com/js/widget.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","zl-widget-s");</script>
```